Solve constrained optimization of simplified Fredholm integral
I'm trying to solve a constrained minimization problem. I suspect it can be done using a mix of the Coarea formula and the radon transform, but I'm not sure how. If the constrained problem is too hard, I've got a easier version of the problem that I'd also like solved.
Find $W(s,\alpha)$ given that I know $f(x,y)$. If it helps, I know that $f(x,y)=0$ outside the unit circle and is greater than $0$ inside the unit circle. $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and $g(s,\alpha,x,y)$ is a line given by:
\begin{equation}
g=x\cos(\alpha)+y\sin(\alpha)-s
\end{equation}
Constrained problem (hard):
\begin{equation}
\textrm{min} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Bigg[f(x,y) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}W(s,\alpha)\delta(g)d\alpha ds \Bigg]^2 dxdy
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textrm{subject to}\\ 0 \leq W(s,\alpha) \leq 1
\end{equation}
Unconstrained problem (easier): Incase the above problem is too hard, the unconstrained problem reduces to solving:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}W(s,\alpha)\delta(g)d\alpha ds
\end{equation}
